# Java Integration tests between mobile and API. What is the best approach?

Tags: java, android, api, integration-testing

I am implementing some integration tests here between my mobile apk and the server API. I am using JAVA and Robotium for the UI tests. I need send some Json requests to the server and check if the behaviour on the app is correct after this change.

I have suggested create the jsons in a script and inside of the a step of the scenario (Given step) send this json to the server, but this would duplicate the effort when maintaining the scenario on server automation (Jmeter scripts) and mobile automation (Cucumber-JVM and Robotium).

Is anyone has an idea how I could implement integrated tests between the mobile app and the server API without duplicating the scenarios on both of the automations ?

Comment: Restating the question, you can send tests to the mobile API using Cucumber-jvm and Robotium and you can send tests to the server API using Jmeter. Right so far?  You sending canned JSON to the server would not constitute an "integrated test". For an integrated test you would need to simulate some user action on the mobile device that in turn triggered an exchange with the server.

Comment: Something is unclear. Performans scripts should not be related integration testing. You should assert the result of the interaction in Then block by sending request to API.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56  I would simulate the user action with Robotium on the mobile device in the Then step. Checking if what I've sent to the server is reflecting on the UI. My question is how could be the approach for this integration test ? 

Should I call the jmeter requests inside the steps of my mobile automation ?
Should I send all the json requests before the mobile automation and check the UI after ?
Should I create a helper to send the json requests inside the Given step and check the UI in the Then step?

Comment: @MesutGüneş I gave the example of Jmeter, because I am testing the server part (isolated) sending requests through Jmeter for now. It was just because I already have the script with the requests, but nothing that I could code on my mobile automation project. I've commented above, maybe it is more clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a strategy to do the integration tests between the app and the server API, google suggests Hermetic tests:

http://googletesting.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/hermetic-servers.html

http://googletesting.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/android-ui-automated-testing.html

Some good points are:
- You are not mocking the server anymore
- You don't need to worry about to maintain the mock server and the test
- You are running without need a network connection
- The tests are more reliable